# Program not save and update new data in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I create program stock management system by using Django. Page of Update_items that create for saving and updating. Program can running but when I will update new data it can't save and update data. It will redirect with same data. I'm not sure whatit's wrong. I am very new so please introduce me.
This is from views.py

```
from email import header
from multiprocessing import context
from urllib import request
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect


import stockmgmt
from .models import Stock
from .forms import StocksearchForm,StockCreateForm,StockUpdateForm



def home(request):
    title = 'ยินดีต้อนรับเข้าสู่ระบบสต็อคสินค้าเซียงกง'
    form =  'Welcome: This is the Home Page'
    context = {
        "title": title,
        "test": form,    
    }
    return render(request, "home.html",context)

def list_items(request):
    title = 'รายการสินค้า'
    form = StocksearchForm(request.POST or None)
    queryset = Stock.objects.all()
    context = {
        "title": title,  
        "queryset": queryset,
        "form":form
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        queryset = Stock.objects.filter(category__icontains=form['category'].value(),item_name__icontains=form['item_name'].value(),id_product__icontains=form['id_product'].value(),shop_name__icontains=form['shop_name'].value())
                 
        context ={
        "form":form,
        "header": header,
        "queryset": queryset,
     
    }
    return render(request, "list_items.html",context)

def add_items(request):
    form=StockCreateForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/list_items')
    context={
        "form":form,
        "title":"Add Item",
    }
    return render(request,"add_items.html",context)
def update_items(request, pk):
        queryset = Stock.objects.get(id=pk)
        form = StockUpdateForm(instance=queryset)
        if request.method == ' POST':
                form = StockUpdateForm (request.POST, instance=queryset)
                if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                        return redirect('/list_items')
        context = {
                'form':form
        }
        return render(request, 'add_items.html', context)
```

This is list_items.html

```
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    

</body>
</html>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">

    <title>รายการสินค้า</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbar-top-fixed/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href ="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel ="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    
    
    <link href="navbar-top-fixed.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
    
  

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">สต็อคสินค้าร้านเซียงกง</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/">หน้าแรก <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/list_items">รายการสินค้า</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/add_items">เพิ่มรายการสินค้า</a>
              </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        
        
        <h1>รายการสินค้า</h1>
        
        <form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
            {{form|crispy}}
            <input type="submit" value='Search'/>
        </form>
        <br>
        
        <table class='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>รายการสินค้า</th>
                    <th>ประเภทสินค้า</th>
                    <th>ชื่อสินค้า</th>
                    <th>รหัสสินค้า</th>
                    <th>ชื่อร้าน</th>
                    <th>ราคา/หน่วย</th>
                    <th>จำนวนที่มีอยู่ในร้าน</th>
                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
        {% for instance in queryset %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                <td>{{instance.category}}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'update_items' instance.id %}">{{instance.item_name}}</a></td>
                <td>{{instance.id_product}}</td>
                <td>{{instance.shop_name}}</td>
                <td>{{instance.price}}</td>
                <td>{{instance.quantity}}</td>
                
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>


      </div>

    </main>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is url.py

```
"""djangoproject URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from stockmgmt import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('list_items/', views.list_items, name='list_items'),
    path('add_items/', views.add_items, name='add_items'),
    path('update_items/<str:pk>/', views.update_items, name="update_items"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

[This is my error in command promopt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afjTP.png)

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

## In forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Stock

# Create your forms here
class StockForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        # incase you want all fields
        fields = '__all__'
```

## In views.py

```
from .forms import StockForm
from .models import Stock
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import messages


def update_entry(request, pk):
    try:
        queryset = Stock.objects.get(id=pk)
    except Stock.DoesNotExist:
        messages.error(request, "The request entry does not exist.")
        # Redirect back some page incase of invalid pk
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("app2:listing"))
    # Populate the form with old data
    form = StockForm(instance=qs)
    context = {"form": form}
    # When method is post
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Populate the form with newly posted data
        form = StockForm(request.POST, instance=qs)
        # Checking data validity in form
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # Always use HttpResponseRedirect after successfull post request
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("some-url-name"))
        # When form is not valid re-render page
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid form received.")
            # Update form in context dictionary
            context["form"] = form
            return render(request, "update-stock.html", context)
    # When method is not post
    else:
        return render(request, "update-stock.html", context)
```

## In update-stock.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Loop over messages rendered from views -->
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ message }}</strong>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <form method="post" action="" class="row g-1">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried follow your comment but it's not working. It still not update and redirect with same page and same data. Plz tell me another way thank you

Comment: Try to debug your program using print, for example after ```if form.is_valid():``` on the next line before ```form.save()``` print("Valid Form Received") and then check your console.